# Azure SDK 1.4 - Cannot debug in VS2010 with multiple sites

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I have a newly installed laptop running Win7/x64 and installed Visual Studio 2010, then VS2010 SP1, and then the Windows Azure SDK 1.4.

When I attempt to debug a cloud service project in the local compute emulator environment, I get an error: "The was an error attaching the debugger to the IIS worker process for URL 'http://127.0.0.1:5102/' for role instance..."

Some searching turned up quite a few discussions on this issue with the Azure SDK 1.3 update and I've narrowed down the issue to my having multiple sites in the same Web Role in my Azure application. If I comment out the sites entries in the ServiceDefinition.csdef, there's no error and debugging works fine. I tried the other recommended solutions, reinstalling .NET, re-registering ASP, rebooting while facing Redmond, but same problem.

I'm surprised by this issue on a new VS/Azure 1.4 installation and I'm hoping someone else has resolved supporting multiple sites for local debug.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and have two suggestions:

- If you've pointed to the "Published" output of a website and not the source location in ServiceDefinition.csdef, you'll get this error.  Point to the source location of the web site when you're debugging.  You can always switch the location later if you'd rather deploy a published web site rather than the source.
- Ensure that you have debug set to false in the each of the web application's web.config file.  While obvious, this catches me from time to time.